# Rails link_to to generate URL with subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionview

In my routes file I have the line:

```
match 'documents/:category/:id' => 'documents#show'
```

allowing me to use URLs like:

*localhost:3000/documents/lesson_plans/day_01*

The URL works correctly, but I can't figure out how to generate it using link_to.

---

```
link_to 'day_01', document_path('/lesson_plans/day_01')
```

returns the error:

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"documents",
>   :id=>"/lesson_plans/day_01"}

---

```
link_to 'day_01', document_path(:category => 'lesson_plans', :id => 'day_01')
```

works, but it generates the URL:

> localhost:3000/documents/day_01?category=lesson_plans

which isn't clean enough.

---

Is there a way to generate the URL:

> **localhost:3000/documents/lesson_plans/day_01**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
match 'documents/:category/:id' => 'documents#show', :as => :document
```

and

```
= link_to 'day_01', document_path('day_01', :category => 'lesson_plans')
```

It should generate:

```
http://localhost:3000/documents/lesson_plans/day_01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to "day_01", {:controller => :documents, :action => :show, :category => "lesson_plans", :id => "day_01"} %>
```